# In a Rust Tonic gRPC server, how to close the network connection after receiving a malicious request?

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tonic

Rust Tonic generates the following interface for a simple "hello-world" application:

```
  pub trait HelloworldService: Send + Sync + 'static {
      async fn sayhello(
          &self,
          request: tonic::Request<super::UserInput>,
      ) -> Result<tonic::Response<super::UserInputResponse>, tonic::Status>;
      
  }
```

After implementing function `sayhello` and starting a tonic server, everything works as expected.

My question is:

If I check the input `UserInput` object and decide that the current user input is malicious (say, contain an empty security token), I'd like to immediately close the network connection without feeding any response (not even some error msg/code) to the client-side, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tonic doesn't seem to have an API to access the underlying network. Had to dig deeper all the way down to hyper h2 server (hyper/src/proto/h2/server.rs). In the implementation of struct `H2Stream` (`impl<F, B, E> H2Stream<F, B> where ...`), there is a function `poll2()`, which is called to poll the state of `H2Stream`. That function contains the following piece of code that apparently inserts the current time into the response header before sending it over to the client.

```
 // set Date header if it isn't already set...
                    res.headers_mut()
                        .entry(::http::header::DATE)
                        .or_insert_with(date::update_and_header_value);
```

This leads to the following idea: add a flag in the response returned from `HelloworldService::sayhello()` when detecting a malicious request, then check that flag in `H2Stream::poll2()`, if the flag is presented, immediately return from `H2Stream::poll2()` with `return Poll::Ready(Ok(()))`, this will drop the stream and hence the connection.

Http response `Extensions` are used to carry that flag. It is set by `sayHello()` in the `Extensions` field of `tonic::Response`, and that field is carried over to the `Extensions` field of `http::response::Response`, which is checked by `H2Stream::poll2()`.

This apparent hack seems to work. But is there a better idea?